# Is FlexibleContexts really needed in this context?

Tags: haskell

**The question I posted makes no sense.**

The type signatures were provided by ghci.

I misread it: not **(MonadReader (Map k (Set a -> Set a)) m**;

but rather: **MonadReader (Map k (Set a -> Set a) m)**.

It was just an oversight. Sorry for wasting your time.

========================================

Is FlexibleContexts really needed in this context?

Which monad does "m" stand for?

I tried replacing "m" with [ ], but it didn't work.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module LeftCensorsList where

import Data.Set as S
import Data.Map as M
import Data.List as L
import Control.Monad.Reader

-- ============================== FUNCTIONS ==============================

censorsList :: Ord a => Map a (Set a -> Set a) -> [Set a] -> ([Set a], [Set a])
censorsList _ [] = ([],[])
censorsList cnsrmap (xs:xss) = runReader (go xs xss [xs]) cnsrmap
    where
    go _ [] invacc = pure (reverse invacc,[])
    go cnsrs (ys:yss) invacc = do
        ys' <- applyCensors cnsrs ys
        if S.null ys'
          then pure (reverse invacc,ys:yss)
          else go ys' yss (ys': invacc)        

applyCensors :: (MonadReader (Map k (Set a -> Set a)) m, Ord k) => Set k -> Set a -> m (Set a)  -- <<<<<
applyCensors cnsrs xs = go (S.toList cnsrs) xs
    where
    go [] ys = pure ys
    go (cnsr:rest) ys = do
        ys' <- applyCensor cnsr ys    
        if S.null ys'
          then pure S.empty
          else go rest ys'        

applyCensor :: (MonadReader (Map k (t -> t)) m, Ord k) => k -> t -> m t -- <<<<<
applyCensor cnsr xs = do
    cnsrmap <- ask
    case M.lookup cnsr cnsrmap of
        Nothing -> pure xs
        Just f  -> pure $ f xs

-- ============================== TEST ==============================
 
t1,t2,t3, t4 :: ([Set Int],[Set Int])
t1 = censorsList M.empty $ L.map S.fromList [[1,3,13],[2,4,6]]  -- ok
t2 = censorsList exCensorsMap $ L.map S.fromList [[1,3,13],[2,4,6]]  -- ok
t3 = censorsList exCensorsMap []  -- ok
t4 = censorsList exCensorsMap $ L.map S.fromList [[1,4,13],[2,4,5]]  -- ok

-- ============================== EXAMPLES ==============================

-- -------------------- MAPS --------------------

exCensorsMap :: Map Int (Set Int -> Set Int)
exCensorsMap = M.fromList $
    [(1,censor1)
    ,(2,censor2)
    ,(3,censor3)
    ,(4,censor4)
    ]
 
-- -------------------- CENSORS --------------------

censor1, censor2, censor3, censor4 :: Set Int -> Set Int
censor1 = \xs -> xs S.\\ (S.fromList [2,4])
censor2 = \xs -> xs S.\\ (S.fromList [3])
censor3 = \xs -> xs S.\\ (S.fromList [1,2])
censor4 = \xs -> xs S.\\ (S.fromList [2,5])
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `FlexibleContexts`? That's required most applications of miltiparameter type classes.

Comment: @dfeuer  It's just a curiosity.

Comment: Yes `MonadReader (Map k (Set a -> Set a)) m` requires `FlexibleContexts`, because that's not of the simple form like `Ord k`. The option you need to beware of is `FlexibleInstances`, which can allow in overlapping instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monad you are instantiating is the reader monad:

```
applyCensors :: (Ord k) => Set k -> Set a -> Reader (Map k (Set a -> Set a)) (Set a)
```

You can infer this yourself by noting the type of `runReader` and unifying from there.

Answer (score 0):

The type signatures were provided by ghci.
I misread it: not (MonadReader (Map k (Set a -> Set a)) m;
but rather: MonadReader (Map k (Set a -> Set a) m).
It was just an oversight and therefore **the question makes no sense.**

Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Err by asking more questions, not fewer.